# Move image across screen with CSS3

Tags: image, css, animation, transition

I've been browsing the web for quite awhile trying to find a way of making icons move onto the screen (from the left and onto the center of the body div) when you load the page. How can this be done?

This is what I have so far:

CSS3

```
a#rotator {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left;
}

a#rotator img {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
    border-radius:60px;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    }

a#rotator img:hover { 
    box-shadow: 0 3px 15px #000;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); 
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); 
    transform: translate()
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want a pure CSS solution, you can use the CSS3 animation feature.
You create or declare a animation with the keyword `@animation` followed by the name you want to give to that animation. Inside the curly brackets you must indicate the keyframes of the animation and what CSS properties will be applied in that keyframe, so the transition between keyframes is done.
You must specify at least two keyframes, the beginning and the end of the animation with the keywords `from` and `to`, followed by the properties inside curly brackets. For example:

```
@keyframes myanimation
{
    from {
        left: 0;
    }
    to {
        left: 50%;
    }
}
```

Or a example with three keyframes (the percent indicates the percent of the duration):

```
@keyframes myanimation
{
    0% {
        left: 0;
    }
    10% {
        left: 50%;
    }
    100% {
        left: 10%;
    }
}
```

Once you have created the animation, you must specify which element you want to animate, it's just the `animation` property inside the CSS rule that matches the element. Note that the name in the value must match the one that you've created before, and you the duration of the animation. For example:

```
a#rotator {
    animation: myanimation 5s;
}
```

Here you can specify the duration, number of times that it must be repeated, etc. You can read the full specs here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/

Here you can see a working example with the code you've provided: http://jsfiddle.net/mcSL7/1/

I've stopped floating the element and I've assigned it the position absolute, so I can move it in the body with the top and left properties.

This CSS feature is supported by almost every modern browser, even if some of them need the -webkit- vendor prefix. Check it here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

Comment: Thanks! this is very helpful. Just wondering how you'd do it for 5 images at once instead of just the one?

Comment: If you want all the five at the same time, apply the same class to the five images and apply the animation to the class rule: [http://jsfiddle.net/5q5DQ/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/5q5DQ/1/). If you want them being animated at diferent times, give them id's and apply a different delay for each one, and note the value `forwards` in the animation property, that makes the element still in the last frame position: [http://jsfiddle.net/u5EW6/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/u5EW6/1/)

Comment: Hi @pablopixel, I am trying to do this in 3D. I have tried a few example I have found online however I am having difficulty getting them to work. If you could show how to convert this example to 3D then I will be able to apply that to mine. Regards, Glyn

Comment: Hi @Glyn, do you mean CSS 3D transforms? What have you tried so far? Could you provide a fiddle with it?

Comment: Hi @pablopixel, I have found a solution after much experimentation. Please see "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667081/how-to-stop-an-image-returning-to-its-starting-point-using-css3-rotate3d/26673624?noredirect=1#comment41967107_26673624". In a nut shell, I added the image to a panel and rotated the panel. Regards, Glyn.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery

html

```
<div id="b">&nbsp;</div>
```

css

```
div#b {
    position: fixed;
    top:40px;
    left:0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: url(http://www.wiredforwords.com/IMAGES/FlyingBee.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

script

```
var b = function($b,speed){


    $b.animate({
        "left": "50%"
    }, speed);
};

$(function(){
    b($("#b"), 5000);
});
```

see jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vishnurajv/Q4Jsh/