# How to stop an image returning to its starting point using CSS3 rotate3d

Tags: css

In order to get a ball moving in 3D I have created a new container to contain the image and rotated the container.

The java code is:

```
//Run the play when the "Play Ball" button is selected.
        runButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
        {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {   

                if (play == 1) {

                    //play1();
                    moveBallContainer.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
                    moveBallContainer.setVerticalAlignment(HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_BOTTOM);

                    moveBallContainer.add(img);
                    absolutePanel.add(moveBallContainer, 5, 200);
                    moveBallContainer.addStyleName("roundBall3DMove");
                    answerTextBox1.setCursorPos(0);

                }  
            }
        });
```

The CSS3 is:

```
.roundBall3DMove {
    width: 295px;
    height: 220px;
    position: relative;
    background: grey; /* So I can see what is happening - remove */
    border-radius: 0px;
    perspective: 500px;
    -webkit-animation-name: roundBall3DMove;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    animation-name: roundBall3DMove;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-duration: 2s;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }

  .roundBall3DMove:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
  }

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes roundBall3DMove {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0deg) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg); }
    to   { -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 180deg) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 180deg); }
 }

 /* all other browsers */
  @keyframes roundBall3DMove {
    from {
      -moz-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0deg) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0deg) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
      transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0deg) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
    }
    to {
      -moz-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 180deg) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 180deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 180deg) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 180deg);
      transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 180deg) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 180deg);
    }
  }
```

This gets a movement in 3D. However, at the end of the animation the ball returns to where it started. I do not want this. The ball starts in the lower right of the container and I want to rotate the container in x, y, z axis so the ball ends up in the top left corner and then keep it there.

Regards,

Glyn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of fiddling around with it I found that if I adjust the x axis "rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 180deg);" to, for example, "rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg); then it does not return to the original position.

Regards, Glyn

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add the **[animation-fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)** property and set it to forwards.  The animation-fill-mode property accepts: forwards where the animation will apply the property values for the time the animation **ended**; backwards applies the property values defined in the keyframe that will start the first iteration of the animation; and both, which will honor rules for both forwards and backwards.

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
-moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
animation-fill-mode:forwards;
```

Note that this property is not supported in Android browsers below 2.3.  For more information about support see: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

Comment: Hi @jme11, I already have "animation-fill-mode:forwards;". However, thank you very much for your answer I really do appreciate your effort. I will continue to experiment. Regards, Glyn

Comment: Yeah, I see that now.  Sorry, somehow I missed it earlier.

Comment: Hi @jme11, after a lot of fiddling around with it I found that if I adjust the x axix "rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 180deg);" to, for example, "rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg); then it does not return to the original position. Regards, Glyn

Comment: Awesome.  Good to know.  I've seen similarly unexpected side behavior with using for example 270deg but never in this context.  You should post the answer and mark it as accepted for the benefit of others.  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Hi @jme11, Yes I have posted and marked. I have a lot of learning to do yet. So I will be experimenting and posting. However, I am learning and enjoying this. So thank you. Regards, Glyn