# I want to move boostrap cards from left to right automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, css-animations

I have created boostrap cards i want to move(slide) cards from left to right.

Student's Reviews 
  Read what our students and graduates have to say about DevNation

  
    
      
        
       
         Abdul Rehman
         Batch1: Software Engineer
      
     
      
        
          "DevNation is the best platform for developers to improve your skill and get expert in it. With experienced mentors, I can say it's the best teaching organization in Pakistan. It worked on my skills and helped me understand the development techniques better. I consider myself lucky to be a part of DevNation"
        
      
   
    
    
        
                
        
      
        
          
         
           Zeenat Perveen
           Batch1: FrontEnd developer
        
        
          
            "DevNation is a prime choice to learn web development skill. Very skilled teachers with quality of advanced knowledge and great mentoring skills. Learn new skill with practical work and get professional experience. Best recommended platform to improve your skills and make your career successful"

```
  <div class="card bg-primary" style="width: 22rem;">
    <div class="card-header d-flex">
      <img src="./img/Fariha Rajput.jpeg" alt="Fariha Rehman" width="20%" style="border-radius: 20%;">
     <div class="card-header d-block">
       <h4 class="card-title d-inline">Fariha Rehman</h4>
       <div class="card-subtitle ">Software Engineer</div>
    </div></div>
    <div class="card-text">
      <p class="card-paragraph d-block">
        "I feel better prepared to dealing with uncomfortable issues and challenging coding problems. I feel proud to be a part of this tremendous training. Words cannot express how much this training means to me and I am grateful to the DevNation Team"
      </p>
    </div>
 
  </div>

 <!--4th Student-->
 
 <div class="card bg-primary" style="width: 22rem;">
  <div class="card-header d-flex">
    <img src="./img/Hamza Masood.jpeg" alt="Hamza Masood" width="20%" style="border-radius: 20%;">
   <div class="card-header d-block">
     <h4 class="card-title d-inline">Hamza Masood</h4>
     <div class="card-subtitle ">Software Engineer</div>
  </div></div>
  <div class="card-text">
    <p class="card-paragraph d-block">
      "DevNation is a great platform which has helped me to gear up with new skills. Thank you for getting me over the hurdles, having faith in my abilities, and having the skills to get me where I needed to go. I couldn’t have done it without you"
    </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Showing what you have tried will help you get a good answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23185136/7978627

Comment: i could not understand this. I want to move cards not images

Comment: Moving a card is the same as moving an image, its still a keyframe css animation. Instead of attaching it to an img tag, you attach it to the div you want to move.